# 2D FFT of a gaussian in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, fft

I have a problem calculating the 2D FFT of a gaussian. When I use the function plt.imshow(), the FFT is correct. But when I try to plot it as a function of the spatial frequencies, 3/4 of the FFT is cut.

What am I doing wrong?

In addition, I always used this method calculating differential equations. There it all worked fine.

Best,
Victor

My code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

L=1
N=2048

#print(shape)
x = np.arange(-L,L,2.*L/N)

y= np.arange(-L,L,2.*L/N)

xx, yy=np.meshgrid(x,y)
#print(xx,yy)
#print(np.size(x))
kx= np.fft.fftfreq(np.size(x),2.*L/N)
ky=np.fft.fftfreq(np.size(y),2.*L/N)
kxx,kyy= np.meshgrid(kx,ky)
#print(xx)

gauss= np.exp(xx**2+yy**2)
#print(gauss)

plt.figure()
plt.pcolormesh(xx,yy, gauss)
plt.gca().set_aspect("equal") 
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()


FFT=np.fft.fft2(gauss)
FFT_Shift = np.fft.fftshift(FFT)
FFT_Log= np.log(FFT)
#print(FFT)

plt.figure()
# This one does not work
plt.pcolormesh(kxx,kyy,abs(np.fft.fftshift(FFT_Log)))
# However, using imshow works fine
#plt.imshow(abs(FFT_Log)) # This one works
plt.gca().set_aspect("equal") 
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but one thing I noticed: ``np.exp(xx**2+yy**2)`` is not a gaussian. Perhaps you meant ``np.exp(-(xx**2+yy**2))``?

Comment: yes this was a copy paste error.  But, I missed some of my code.:  I use imshow(abs(FFT_Log)), then the FFT is a gaussian. But as i plot it with colormesh (with the frequencies on the x and y axis) the FFT is not a gaussian.

Comment: Oh. It looks like you're FFT-shifting the data, but not FFT-shifting the frequency grid. I'd wager that's why the result doesn't look how you expect.

Comment: Also, it's strange that you're taking the log of the (complex) FFT. The complex logarithm is a strange beast... what are you trying to accomplish with that?